# Override element.style in CSS

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a react component using React-qr-scanner but I cannot seem to override the element.style. I want to remove the border because it's too big.

[image]

```
.qrScanner {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) !important;
  box-shadow: rgba(244, 248, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 0px 5px inset;
}
```

I'm calling it by

```
<QrReader
            delay={3000}
            onError={handleError}
            onScan={handleScan}
            // chooseDeviceId={()=>selected}
            style={{width: '250px', heigth: '200px'}}
            className={'qrScanner'}
          />
```

I want to override it using CSS.

Comment: Did you try `!important`?

Comment: yes sir, I have important on all style.

Comment: Inline styling overrides all other styles applied to it, not the vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Style takes precedence over CSS. You'll have to hack or fork the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try appending your custom style inline to existing one